# different between "getDocumentElement" and "getFirstChild"

Tags: java, xml, nodes, document

I have the following `Document` object - `Document myDoc`.

`myDoc` holds an `XML` file by...

```
myDoc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
```

Now I want to get the root of the XML file.  Is there any difference between

```
Node firstChild = this.myDoc.getFirstChild()
```

and

```
Node firstChild = (Node)myDoc.getDocumentElement()
```

In the first way, `firstChild` holds a node root of an `XML` file but it will not have the depth of `Node`. However, in the second way, `firstChild` will be the root with all of the depth.

For example, I have the following XML

```
<inventory>
    <book num="b1">
    </book>
    <book num="b2">
    </book>
    <book num="b3">
    </book>
</inventory>
```

and `file` holds it.

In the 1st case, `int count = firstChild.getChildNodes()`  gives  `count = 0`.

The 2nd case will give `count = 3`.

Am I right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Node you get using myDoc.getFirstChild() may not be the document root if there are other nodes before the document root node - such as a comment node. Look at the example below:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class ReadXML {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{     

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // Document elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(args[0]));

        Node firstChild = doc.getFirstChild();
        System.out.println(firstChild.getChildNodes().getLength());
        System.out.println(firstChild.getNodeType());
        System.out.println(firstChild.getNodeName());

        Node root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        System.out.println(root.getChildNodes().getLength());
        System.out.println(root.getNodeType());
        System.out.println(root.getNodeName());

    }
}
```

When parsing the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>    
   </product>
</catalog>
```

gives the following result:

```
0
8
#comment
3
1
catalog
```

But if I remove the comment, it gives:

```
3
1
catalog
3
1
catalog
```